# How to get rid of an extra Maybe

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, option-type

I have a function that might fail, so the value it returns needs to be wrapped in a Maybe. It uses another function that might also fail, and that is also wrapped in a Maybe. The problem is, to get the types to work out in an intermediate calculation, I have to "prematurely" lift a function to work in the Maybe context. That results in my getting a type Maybe [Maybe Integer], when what I want is Maybe [Integer]. The function in question is the exptDecipherString function, the function that's forcing "premature" lifting is the modularInverse function.

```
import Data.Char
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Math.NumberTheory.Powers

--Helpers

extendedGcd::Integer->Integer->(Integer, Integer)
extendedGcd a b | r == 0 = (0, 1)
                | otherwise = (y, x - (y * d))
                where
                    (d, r) = a `divMod` b
                    (x, y) = extendedGcd b r

modularInverse::Integer->Integer->Maybe Integer
modularInverse n b | relativelyPrime n b = Just . fst $ extGcd n b
                   | otherwise = Nothing
                   where
                        extGcd = extendedGcd

relativelyPrime::Integer->Integer->Bool
relativelyPrime m n = gcd m n == 1 

textToDigits::String->[Integer]
textToDigits = map (\x->toInteger (ord x - 97)) 

digitsToText::[Integer]->String
digitsToText = map (\x->chr (fromIntegral x + 97)) 

--Exponentiation Ciphers

exptEncipher::Integer->Integer->Integer->Maybe Integer
exptEncipher m k p | relativelyPrime k (m - 1) = Just $ powerMod p k m 
                   | otherwise = Nothing

exptDecipher::Integer->Integer->Integer->Maybe Integer
exptDecipher m q c | relativelyPrime q (m - 1) = Just $ powerMod c q m
                   | otherwise = Nothing

exptEncipherString::Integer->Integer->String->Maybe [Integer]
exptEncipherString m k p | relativelyPrime k (m - 1) = mapM (exptEncipher m k) plaintext
                         | otherwise = Nothing
    where
        plaintext = textToDigits p

exptDecipherString::Integer->Integer->[Integer]->Maybe String
exptDecipherString m k c | relativelyPrime k (m - 1) = fmap digitsToText plaintext
                         | otherwise = Nothing
    where
        q = modularInverse k (m - 1)
        plaintext = mapM (exptDecipher m <$> q <*>) (map pure c)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you should usually try for "How can X become Y" is [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe%20%28Maybe%20a%29%20-%3E%20Maybe%20a).  In this case, it recommends you use `join`, which will collapse two `Maybe`s into one.

With some code restructuring, the `Maybe` monad could also be used to help you here.

When all else fails, roll your own solution that uses functions or a case statement with pattern matching.

Comment: I tried Hoogle, maybe I'm being dumb about how to use it. I typed in "Monad m => m m a-> m a" or something to that effect. I'm still trying to figure out how to think in types :(

Comment: @JoshInfiesto Your query is almost right!  You've just forgotten some parentheses.  Try `Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` instead, then think about why that query works.

Comment: @JoshInfiesto, yes, just as function application.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Hoogle is smart enough that a query for `Maybe (Maybe Integer) -> Maybe Integer` will produce `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` as its first result.